# Upper-bound for positive roots of $\sum_{j=1}^d 1 / (x + \lambda_j) = c$, where the $\lambda_j$'s are fixed nonnegative reals

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, reference-request, roots, rational-functions

Let $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_d$ be positive numbers and let $0 \lt c \le d$.

> **Question.** What is a **good** upper-bound for the  positive solutions of the equation
> $$
> \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{x+\lambda_j} = c.
> \tag{1}
> $$

Note that if we rewrite the above equation as
$$
\tag{2}
c x^d + a_{d-1}x^{d-1} + \ldots a_1 x + a_0=0,
$$
for some $a_{d-1},\ldots,a_0 \in \mathbb R$ with $a_d=c$ and $a_0=c\Pi_j\lambda_j - \sum_j \lambda_j$. then an upper-bound is given by
$$
B := 2\cdot \max_{a_j a_d \lt 0} |a_j/a_d|^{1/2}.
\tag{3}
$$

See this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_of_positive_real_roots.

However, I don't see a simple way to write the $a_j$'s a function of the $\lambda_j$'s, for $1 \le  j \le d-1$, in order to exploit (3).

Answer (score 1):

Denote $x_0$ be the largest positive root and  $p_i = \frac{1}{\lambda_i}$ for $i=1,...,d$, then

$$c  = \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{1}{x_0+\lambda_i} =\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{p_i}{p_ix_0+1}  \tag{1}$$

The function $f(p) = \frac{p}{px_0+1}$ is concave over the domain $p>0$ because
$$f''(p) = -\frac{2x_0}{(1+px_0)^3} < 0$$
Then we can apply the Jensen's inequality to $(1)$
$$c=\sum_{i=1}^d f(p_i) \le d\cdot f\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^d p_i}{d}\right ) = d\cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^d p_i}{x_0\sum_{i=1}^d p_i+d} =  \frac{d}{x_0+\frac{d}{\sum_{i=1}^d p_i}}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x_0 \le  \color{red}{\frac{d}{c} -\frac{d}{\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{1}{\lambda_i}} }$$

Comment: Thanks for the input. Upvoted. I forgot to say that I mean a good upper-bound, and I also forgot to say that I'm already away of the upper-bound you propose, but I'm not satisfied with it because it discards all the $\lambda $'s except the smallest one. In particular, such an upper-bound is arbitrarily bad when the lambdas decay even only mildly fast. E.g $\lambda_i = 1/i^\alpha$.

Comment: @dohmatob I made the upper bound stricter. Now, all $\lambda_i$ are used.